# How to invoke a handler stored in a variable in Applescript

Tags: applescript

New to AppleScript, it looks variables can be set to scripts or handlers:

```
on Foo()
    log "Foo"
end Foo

on Bar()
    log "Bar"
end Bar

set myHandlers to {Foo, Bar}
set x to the first item in myHandlers
log x -- <<handler Foo>>
```

Now how do I invoke 'x'? Couldn't find this information in official docs; tried some keywords like "run", "exec", all not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that – it's an undefined behavior and doesn't work as expected. (AppleScript handlers are not closures.) The correct way is to wrap each handler in a script objects and assign those:

```
script Foo
  on doit()
    log "Foo"
  end doit
end script

script Bar
  on doit()
    log "Bar"
  end doit
end script

set myHandlers to {Foo, Bar}
set x to the first item in myHandlers
x's doit() -- logs "Foo"
```

There are some [examples here](https://github.com/alldritt/applescript-stdlib) [1] which you may find helpful; e.g. see the `List` library's `sort list` command and the `Text` library's `search text` commands, both of which take optional parameters that use this technique to enable user-customizable behaviors.

---

[1] BTW, also feel free to dupe my [Radar ticket](http://openradar.appspot.com/28465563) requesting Apple include those libraries in 10.13; the more requests they get the more likely they are to do it.